# Run-time '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error though the code still works

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code to apply conditional formatting in a cell based on the value of its adjacent cell - say, format A2 based on A1. However, after finishing running the code, I encountered an Run-time 1004 Error, even though my code still worked.

Error: Run-time '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error

```
Sub CodForAr()
 Dim iSet As IconSetCondition

 NumOfRows = Range("SKUs").Rows.Count + 1
 With Range("SKUs")
 For i = 1 To NumOfRows
     Set iSet = .Cells(i, 2).FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
     With iSet
         .IconSet = IconSets(xl3Arrows)
         .ReverseOrder = False
         .ShowIconOnly = False
     End With
     With iSet.IconCriteria(2)
         .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
         .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
         .Value = Range("SKUs").Cells(i, 1).Value
     End With
     With iSet.IconCriteria(3)
         .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
         .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
         .Value = Range("SKUs").Cells(i, 1).Value
     End With
 Next i
 End With
End Sub
```

### I was just wondering what caused the error even though the code still gave me the desired result?

So actually, I found the troublesome part, it lies at this line of code

```
NumOfRows = Range("SKUs").Rows.Count + 1
```

which basically extend my range length to one more cell whose value is invalid, which caused the error. However another a problem I encountered is that 
[Error cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIBSx.png)

The code work perfectly till the yellow highlighted cells for whichever reasons. Anyone has any hypothesis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define a parent worksheet for every instance that you use `Range("SKUs")`? If this isn't in a worksheet's private code sheet, the parent worksheet of the named range should be explicit, not implicit.

Comment: @user10862412 there is nothing wrong with that part of the code, provided `SKUs` is a **Workbook** scoped reference.  The named range bring with it the sheet reference.

Comment: @Eddy How and where is `IconSets` defined?  Also, is every value in `Range("SKUs")` a valid criteria value?  I get that error if there are blanks in  `Range("SKUs")`

Comment: Your intentions are not clear. You can not implement your intentions properly with code alone. It would be good to describe what you want to do

Comment: @chrisneilsen IconSets is a method in VBA, it's a part of conditional formatting function, and yet Range("SKUs") is a valid criteria and all filled in with a value.

Comment: I've just edited my post. Can you have a look to see if you know what the issue here is? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how that is correctly performing the conditional formatting operation that you want to perform unless xl3Arrows is the default **IconSet**.

In short, IconSet is singular, not plural.

```
 With iSet
     .IconSet = IconSet(xl3Arrows)
     .ReverseOrder = False
     .ShowIconOnly = False
 End With
```

I'll suggest you start using Option Explicit by toggling on the VBE's Tools, Options, Editor, Require variable declaration and stop using `On Error Resume Next` as a stop-gap to bypass obvious (and easily fixable) coding errors.

The last 37 minutes might have been well spent putting some rudimentary debugging methods to practical use.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The OP is using the property `IconSet` as in `With iSet   .IconSet = ...`.  Since the OP states they get a Run Time Error, we must assume `IconSets` is defined elsewhere (otherwise there would be a Compile Time Error)

Comment: The IconSets is in fact plural, I have double checked in VBA, once I changed it into singular, there will be Compile Time Error as @chrisneilsen stated above. And this is just a standalone code, which isn't called from another sub, I'm still a beginner so not sure if I know what you mean though.

Comment: I've just edited my post. Could you have a look and let me know if you know what kind of issue I have here please? Thanks

Comment: `IconSets` is a collection of `IconSet` items. You cannot work on the complete set; you have to select an item

Comment: @PaulOgilvie How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: `For i = 1 to cfItemSet.Count...With cfItemSet.Item(i)...` and see  IconSet  in Excel Help.